# Combining CAS with OAuth

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, cas

We are already using CAS for single sign on for several web applications that we are hosting. Now we are going to deploy several HTTP/REST services in our network and those need authentication and authorization.

Would it be a good idea to combine CAS with OAuth ?

Users would still use CAS for SSO, but additionally login procedure would issue OAuth ticket that would be used to access REST services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's certainly valid. OAuth 2.0 doesn't specify/dictate how the user (Resource Owner) is authenticated and CAS/SSO is fine for that. Effectively you'd be leveraging a CASified Authorization Server so that the Resource Owner authenticates with CAS to the Authorization Server, which is "just" an application to the CAS SSO system. The Authorization Server would then issue an access token down to the Client so that the Client can use that access token to access the protected resources i.e. the REST services.

Answer (score 1):

REST services can be protected via CAS proxy authn. Additionally, they can be integrated with OAuth. CAS provides both OAuth and OIDC protocol functionality as well.